# Did you forget to double-check?

Tags: riddle, word

> Lo! I heard you have gone to war.
>   Alluding to my utter demise.
>   Trees are what you used to fear,
>   blobs of nothing, nothing is best.
>   Return to the start, and commence to walk.
>   Do it no more than once, down these rickety stairs.
>   Take a notice, ignore the spaces in between.
>   No, doomed you are not, lest you count the punctuation.
>   (Count the space here, and ignore the first-born!)
>   Now, talk, flail, and stop right here.
>   Now that you've got what I've meant to say, double check.
>   I would warn you of anything, coming at your door.
>   Trust me, trust me! And say it once more.
>   So trust me, trust me! Did you forget to double-check?

Hints:

> Do not take the first stanza literally. Very few words in it help you, but oh, how important they are!
> The second stanza is really just emphasizing a portion of the first, and does describe a bit about the object.
> I think I've said to much $\tiny\text{ But look at the tag. }$

Comment: Wow! This looks *weird*.

Comment: Can somebody do anything with the letters "lteebnntmeessedoutnle" ? (I can't and I'm going to bed now..) If you wonder: I've looked at the title of the riddle and the first 2 paragraphs one. Stop here.

Comment: @BmyGuest How on earth did you get those letters?

Comment: All letters which appear twice in any word. Double-checked :-) spontaneous idea, but obviously wrong...

Comment: @BmyGuest Oh, wow! That's _really_ clever! Kudos, kudos!

Comment: Conor, don't feel you have to give lots of hints to get it solved fast. The longer a riddle lasts here before being solved, the more respect it gets!

Comment: @randal'thor Oh. I thought it wasn't being solve due to lack of activity. ^^"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is

> A doorbell

Explanation:

> **L**o! I heard you have gone to war.
> A**l**luding to my utter demise.
> Tr**e**es are what you used to fear,
> blo**b**s of nothing, nothing is best.
> Retu**r**n to the start, and commence to walk.
> Do it n**o** more than once, down these rickety stairs.
> Take a n**o**tice, ignore the spaces in between.
> No, doome**d** you are not, lest you count the punctuation.
> (Count the *space* here, and ignore the first-born!)
> Now, talk, fl**a**il, and stop right here.
>
> Now that you've got what I've meant to say, double check.
> I would warn you of anything, coming at your **door**.
> Trust me, trust me! And say it once more.
> So trust me, trust me! Did you forget to double-check?

Hopefully no further clarification is needed.

I was originally going to give up on this line of thought, but then I double checked and realized it was backwards.  True story.

Comment: Another impressive answer!

Comment: @McMagister, you need to remove the "gi" from your username!

Comment: very clever, dear sir :)

Comment: Perfect, nice job! (Truth be told, I got inspired for this whilst falling down a staircase XD)

Comment: Also 'doorbell' sounds like 'double' as in double check :-)